# Trying to translate a curl API request into Swift

Tags: swift, curl, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to take a curl request I have for an AWS lambda function and write Swift code to call it for my iOS app.

> curl -X GET -H "x-api-key: key" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://gvt5bk3.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/default/functionName?mode=0&query_since=5"

That is the curl request (URL and API key are fake).

This is my Swift code. When I run it, it says it decodes to {message:forbidden}. When I run the curl in the terminal it works, but my Swift code does not. How do I fix this?

```
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.addValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "x-api-key")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    } else if let data = data {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
                // Now you have a dictionary representing the JSON data
                print("Decoded JSON: \(json)")
            }
            let postData = try decoder.decode(PostsResponse.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.updatePosts(postData: postData)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Failed to decode: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: Typo: You are ignoring the request `dataTask(with: request)`

Answer (score 0):

Longer answer:

There are several ways to create a data task, including these two methods:

```
URLSession.dataTask(with: URL)
```

and

```
URLSession.dataTask(with: URLRequest)
```

Since you want to provide an API key, you should be using `URLSession.dataTask(with: URLRequest)`. You're calling `URLSession.dataTask(with: URL)` by mistake, and so not providing an API key.

(Vadian already provided this info in a comment, but I thought I'd explain why the incorrect code compiled.